# "Error Removing Linux Kernel Package - GRUB Update Script Issue"

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I'm encountering an issue when trying to remove a specific Linux kernel package on my Ubuntu system. The error seems to be related to a post-removal script that updates the GRUB bootloader configuration. Here are the details of the problem:

I attempted to remove the package linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic using `sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic`.

```
/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux: 1: version_find_latest: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic**
```